# SQL Session State Server dynamic connection string

Tags: sql-server, session-state

I am using a SQL Server for ASP.Net session state. However, I am only able to retrieve the connection string at runtime and for that reason cannot store it in the web.config file. Usually it would be in:

```
<sessionState 
            mode="SQLServer"
            sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=<username>;password=<strongpassword>"
            cookieless="false" 
            timeout="20" 
    />
```

How can I set that connection string at runtime? (i.e. after the web app spins up.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at doing it in the `Application_Start` event in `Global.asax`?  This seems like the logical place to set something like that.

From [MSDN's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx):

> Called when the first resource (such
>   as a page) in an ASP.NET application
>   is requested. The Application_Start
>   method is called only one time during
>   the life cycle of an application. You
>   can use this method to perform startup
>   tasks such as loading data into the
>   cache and initializing static values.
>
> You should set only static data during
>   application start. Do not set any
>   instance data because it will be
>   available only to the first instance
>   of the HttpApplication class that is
>   created.

Comment: Thanks Abe - I knew where to set it I just don't know what to set. I agree that Application_Start is probably the best place to set it just need to know what to override.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you can set that string somewhere within `System.Web.SessionState`, hopefully that will help you get to the right place. Sorry I can't give a better answer, I'm still trying to figure it out myself. If I do, I'll let you know. GL